# How can I set tabs for Visual Studio solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

My defaults for Visual Studio are "keep tabs" and "4 spaces".

But for one C# solution the format command always replaces the tabs with 2 spaces. Only the one solution is affected and I don't see any settings that actually say "2 spaces".

This is affecting another developer (different set of plugins) working on the same solution, so it's got to be a setting somewhere in the project or solution itself. But I can't think of anywhere else to look.

Comment: This is also affecting the ctrl + e, d shortcut to format the code in the whole file. It indents everything to 1 space tabs.

Comment: [Check this out](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/12/15/code-style-configuration-in-the-vs2017-rc-update/).  I think you need to find a file called `.editorconfig`

Comment: @maccettura yup, that did it, I deleted all the overrides there for [*] and now everything is back to normal. Thanks!

Comment: Yes please, I'm sure others have run into this as well.

Comment: @JonathanAllen done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017 [introduced a feature](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/12/15/code-style-configuration-in-the-vs2017-rc-update/) that lets you use the open source "EditorConfig" format to change editor configurations on a "per solution" basis.

You should see a file called `.editorconfig` in your directory.  In there you can see all sorts of settings, I believe the ones you are looking for are:

```
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
```

You can then remove or change depending on your need.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2022

1. Tools --> Options
2. Text Editor --> C# --> Tabs

Comment: That changes it globally, not just for one solution.